# When is $\lim_{\delta x_0\to0} \int_{x_0}^{x_0+\delta x_0}f(x)dx=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

$\int_{x_0}^{x_0} f(x) = 0$ if $f(x_0)$ is defined. Then, for functions that are "nice enough", we should have

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{\delta x_0\to0} \int_{x_0}^{x_0+\delta x_0}f(x)dx=0 \tag1
\end{align}
$$

What are necessary conditions for $f$ so that $(1)$ holds?

I think $f$ needs to be continuous at $x_0$, but how to prove it?

Comment: Continuity is too strong $f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}$ around $x_0$ is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to demand $f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(K)$ for some compact $K$ with $x_0\in K^\circ$ and $\delta x_0$ chosen small enough such that $x_0 + \delta x_0 \in K$. WLOG $x_0 = 0$, rename $\delta x_0$ to $\delta$ for convenience.
$$\lim_{\delta\to 0} \int_0^\delta f(x)\,dx \le \lim_{\delta\to 0} \lambda([0,\delta]) \| f\|_{1,K} = \lim_{\delta \to0} C\delta = 0$$